# Showing that the sequence $(1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},...,\frac{1}{m},\frac{1}{m},...\frac{1}{m},...)\to0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to show that the sequence

$$(x_n)=(1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\dots,\underbrace{\frac{1}{m},\frac{1}{m},\dots,\frac{1}{m}}_{m \text{ times}},...)\to0.$$

I've been trying to bound this sequence from above with a sequence that converges to $0$, but have not been able to show that the bound actually holds (e.g., I tried $1/\sqrt{x}$ but looks like at some point the bound breaks). I'm avoiding the use of analytic expressions for the sequence (this sequence apparently has closed form $x_n=\frac{1}{\lfloor\sqrt{2n}+\frac{1}{2}\rfloor}$) because this was not given in the exercise.

I'm sure there must be some trick to find the appropriate $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ given $\varepsilon>0$ using the fact that the sequence is decreasing, but I have not been able to spot it. (It's worth mentioning that I'm not able to use the fact that being the sequence decreasing and bounded implies that it converges since we have not proved that yet).

I would appreciate any hint or comment on this. Thank you!

Comment: Hint: how far out do you have to go to find the first time the denominator is $m$?

Comment: you may take $n_0=1+2+3+\cdots +m$ to get $x_n\le 1/m$

Comment: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ works. Why did you think it doesn't?

Answer (score 6):

$x_n$ is decreasing and bounded below by $0$ so it converges to the infimum of its image. That is, $\lim x_n=\inf\{1/m\mid m\in\mathbb{N}\}=\lim 1/n=0$.

Edit: I didn't read the part that said that we couldn't use bounded and decreasing implies convergent. Here is a nice trick: Notice that $(x_n^{-1})$ is increasing and unbounded (it's image is $\mathbb{N}$). Let $\varepsilon>0$ and $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that, for $n>N$, $x_n^{-1}>\varepsilon^{-1}$, then $0<x_n<\varepsilon$ for $n>N$.

Comment: Interesting variation: Since $(x_n)_n$ converges and $(1/n)_n$ is a subsequence converging to $0$, then $x_n\to 0$.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to quantify $n_0$, you just need to prove that it exists. So given $\epsilon$, define $n_0$ to be an index in the sequence at which the corresponding $m$ value is larger than $1/\epsilon$. The existence of such an index is implied by the notation used to define the sequence.

The notation also implies that the $m$ sequence never decreases; this is how you can "notice that $(x^{−1}_n)$ is increasing and unbounded" in Sebastián's answer, and the rest of the argument is similar.

The problem is annoyingly written, because one can't give formal proofs of direct observations about an informal definition, and yet the fact that the sequence converges to $0$ is *almost* obvious from the notation used to define it. The validity of a solution boils down to opinions about what's obvious (which will definitely vary, as jjagmath's answer shows).

Comment: (+1) I was thinking the same thing as I was reading through the question and answers, which I saw before getting to your answer at the end (as I write this). What the OP actually wants is an explicit $\varepsilon$-$N$ relation that shows convergence to $0,$ such as would allow one to quantify the *rate of convergence* to $0.$ Of course, in the context of a classroom or a textbook, this is often what is intended despite not being explicitly stated.

Answer (score 1):

From the definition of the sequence we have $x_m=\frac{1}{n}$ precisely for $\frac{(n-1)n}{2}<m\le \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, so
$$x_m=\frac{1}{n}\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}}\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}$$